# Ошибка при регистрации класса

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

Мне необходимо зарегистрировать класс. Как делаю я:

```
procedure registerArr(Classes: array of TPersistentClass);
begin
   RegisterClasses(Classes);
end;

registerArr([TStyleManager
]);
```

Но при компиляции мне выводит эту ошибку

> [dcc32 Error] test.pas(336): E2010 Incompatible types: 'TPersistentClass' and 'class of TStyleManager'

При этом другие классы регистрируются без проблем.

Comment: ваши _другие_ видимо унаследованы от `TPersistentClass`, а вот `TStyleManager` нет.

Comment: проблема как раз в этом.

Comment: расскажите лучше, зачем вам это понадобилось вообще? Очевидно, цепочку наследования вы тут не измените никак. Какую задачу вы с помощью этого хотите решить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Очевидно, зарегистрировать класс `TStyleManager` Вам не удастся по одной простой причине: данный класс *не ведет свою родословную от класса TPersistent*.

### Генеалогическое древо

В модуле `VCL.Themes`, класс `TStyleManager` объявлен следующим образом:

```
  TStyleManager = class sealed
  <...>
  end;
```

Ознакомимся со справкой:

> The System.TObject class, declared in the System unit, *is the ultimate ancestor of all other classes*. <...> If the declaration of a class type does not specify an ancestor, the class inherits directly from System.TObject.

Небольшой перевод:
Класс `TObject` является ультимативным предком *любого класса*. Если не указан *прямой* предок класса, то компилятор, по умолчанию будет считать таковым класс `TObject`.

Выходит, класс `TStyleManager` в качестве предка использует класс `TObject`.

Ошибка, которую Вам выдает компилятор, говорит о несоответствии типов, требующихся для регистрации. Полагаю, Вы уже догадались, что классы `TPersistentClass` и `TObject` являются различными?

Класс `TPersistentClass` объявлен в модуле `System.Classes` и имеет следующий вид:

```
  TPersistentClass = class of TPersistent;
```

### Нарушитель номер один

Безусловно, на ум приходит вот такое *простое решение* - приведение типов.

```
RegisterClasses([TPersistentClass(TStyleManager)]);
```

Но не стоит питать иллюзий относительно работоспособности данного метода в *данном конкретном* случае. Вы получите *гарантированное* сообщение об ошибке.

Вся соль заключается в работе процедуры `RegisterClass`, которая, в свою очередь, вызывается процедурой `RegisterClasses`.
Вот так выглядит "тело" процедуры `RegisterClass` (незначительный код убран):

```
procedure RegisterClass(AClass: TPersistentClass);
begin
  <...>
  while not RegGroups.Registered(AClass) do
  begin
    RegGroups.RegisterClass(AClass);
    if AClass = TPersistent then Break;
    AClass := TPersistentClass(AClass.ClassParent);
  end;
  <...>
end;
```

Класс `TRegGroups` (его экземпляр `RegGroups`) является ответственным за регистрацию классов, поэтому именно к нему обращается цикл, чтобы убедиться: является ли указанный класс зарегистрированным?
Как видно, процедура прекратит проверку регистрации класса и выйдет из цикла только в том случае, если данный класс будет иметь в качестве `ClassParent` класс `TPersistent`. До этого момента цикл будет перебирать цепочку родителей, возвращаемых функцией `ClassParent` до тех пор, пока не встретит искомый результат. Такой подход оправдан для класса `TPersistentClass`, но для классов, предком которых является класс `TObject` такое решение весьма печально. Все дело в работе функции `ClassParent`.

Что говорит нам справка:

> System::TObject::ClassParent returns the name of the parent class for an object instance or class reference. For System::TObject, System::TObject::ClassParent returns nil (Delphi) or NULL (C++). 
>   Avoid using System::TObject::ClassParent in application code.

Иными словами, для класса `TObject` данная функция вернет значение `nil`. Вот почему сделан этот реферанс в сторону использования *только персистентных классов(`TPersistent`)*.

### Мы не используем TObject...

Выше я упоминал *гарантированное сообщение об ошибке*. Это так. Всему виной* работа метода `TRegGroup.RegisterClass`, который имеет следующий вид (незначительный код убран):

```
procedure TRegGroup.RegisterClass(AClass: TPersistentClass);
var
  LClassName: string;
  LClass: TPersistentClass;
begin
  LClassName := AClass.ClassName;
  LClass := GetClass(LClassName);
  <...>
end;
```

Данный метод ожидает на входе *валидный* класс в аргументе `AClass`. Ограничений, введенных программистами Embarcadero в виде применения `TPersistentClass` достаточно, чтобы не делать проверку на `nil` для входящего аргумента. Вместе с тем, именно первое обращение к аргументу и вызывает неизбежное `AccessViolation`.

### За Информацией!

Кто владеет информацией - владеет миром. Шутка ли, но это так. Чтобы <strike>владеть миром</strike> больше понимать о работе тех или иных функций, указанных здесь, советую посетить данные ресурсы:

1. [Classes and Objects](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Classes_and_Objects_(Delphi))
2. [RegisterClasses method](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.Classes.RegisterClasses)
3. [GetClass function](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.Classes.GetClass)
4. [ClassParent function](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/System__TObject__ClassParent.html)
5. Ищите непонятные функции и процедуры в исходных текстах модулей, поставляемых вместе с Delphi.

---

*На самом деле, метод работает так, как от него ожидается при поступлении *корректного* аргумента. Использование метода не по назначению (см. приведение типов выше) не является ошибкой программистов Embarcadero.

Comment: да у вас талант воду лить.

Comment: @teran, что Вы имеете в виду?

Comment: весь смысл вашего ответа находится в первом предложении. Далее изложение всякой всячины, чтобы создать объем, что в простонародье называется "налить воды" в текст. высосанные из пальца заведомо некорректные приведения типов, разбор исходного кода, и т.п. В общем написано много, а по существу - одно предложение.

Comment: @teran, Вы ошибаетесь. Если считать за воду подробное описание причин происходящих процессов, то я тогда даже не знаю, что Вам ответить. Я бы мог не писать такой развернутый ответ, просто указать в комментарии причину. Однако если у человека возникнут вопросы "а почему происходит *именно так*, а не иначе", необходимо будет в *комментариях* объяснять суть. Это не слишком удобно, поэтому я поместил всю *необходимую* информацию сразу в ответ.

Comment: @teran, Вы могли бы сразу дать ответ на вопрос, так как он содержится в Вашем первом комментарии к вопросу. Но Вы этого не сделали. Почему?

Comment: очевидно, потому что я задал еще один вопрос в комментарии. Возможно тут имеет место быть https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/710/223826

Comment: @teran, уточняющие вопросы - это хорошо, но Ваш первый комментарий *есть решение* вопроса. Почему не опубликовать его? ТС четко спросил: почему не регистрируется класс? Вы ответили (в своем комментарии). Вопрос решен. Почему не опубликовали ответ? Не хочется ссориться, тут случайных людей нет, но по-моему, Вы просто придираетесь к размерам моего ответа.

Comment: мой комментарий есть перевод ошибки компилятора. Проблема автора по сути не решена. Что и зачем он пытался сделать осталось загадкой.

Comment: @teran, проблема автора была в невозможности зарегистрировать класс `TStyleManager`. Зачем, как и почему ему это требовалось - нам не должно быть интересно. Он сформулировал вопрос - он получил на него ответ (снова ссылаюсь на Ваш комментарий, который Вы *могли бы опубликовать как ответ*). И если бы автор вопроса хотел, то оставил бы уточнения в комментариях к Вашему ответу, где и пояснил бы что и зачем он собирается делать.

Comment: понимание, как для чего и зачем автору что-то понадобилось, важно для написания хорошего ответа. Автор по незнанию может использовать неправильный инструмент для решения задачи, или выбрать не тот метод решения. Так что я с вами не соглашусь, и предлагаю на этом дискуссию закончить.

Comment: @teran, я Вас все равно не могу постигнуть. Вы бросаетесь из крайности в крайность: то в ответе вода, то автор по незнанию может использовать неправильный инструмент для решения задачи. Вам не кажется, что Вы передергиваете? Ответ полный и четкий, популярно объясняет, почему невозможно добиться того, чего *хотел* ТС в своем изначальном вопросе. Зачем нам знать нюансы, если задача, сформулированная ТС *не решаема*? Ну скажет ТС, что хочет свои скины сделать, и что? Вы сможете зарегистрировать `TStyleManager`? Сомневаюсь.

Comment: @teran, никто не любит критику. Я не исключение. Но если критика по делу - я ее приемлю. Есть что-то,что я упустил в ответе? Если да - скажите, я постараюсь исправить. Если нет - не завидуйте.